# Using "final" or "var" in Dart for-in loop?

Tags: dart

```dart
for (var foo in bar) print(foo);
```

```dart
for (final foo in bar) print(foo);
```

Is there any difference in **performance** between these two? Or is the only difference "avoiding accidental reassignments"?

**Edit:**
[prefer_final_locals](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_final_locals.html) mentions compiler performing optimizations when `final` is used. Will it apply here? `dart2js` output matches for the 2 snippets above. Not sure about `dart2native`.

Comment: It's a good programming practice to use 'final' if the variable is not going to be reassigned. It avoids errors due to wrong assignments.

Comment: I rather doubt that using `final` instead of `var` matters for optimization for local variables.  Even if it mattered, the compiler should be able to easily determine itself whether a local variable is reassigned or not.  Additional skepticism: https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/2103

Answer (score 5):

The only difference is that you can reassign the `foo` value if you use `var`.

```dart
for (var foo in bar) {
  foo = foo + 5;
  print(foo);
}
```

doing so using final would not work

```dart
for (final foo in bar) {
  foo = foo + 5; //Error: The variable foo can be set only once
  print(foo);
}
```

Comment: [prefer_final_locals](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_final_locals.html) mentions that compiler can do optimizations when `final` is used. Will it apply in this case?

Comment: If the compiler cannot recognize that a variable is not reassigned, and optimize it as a final variable when it isn't, the compiler should feel bad. I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score -5):

From Dart Style Guide:

> DON'T use final for local variables.
>
> var is shorter, and final does not change the meaning of the code.

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_final.html

Comment: That's just one option; it's not the standard. In fact that page links to [`prefer_final_locals`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_final_locals.html) which enforces the opposite.

Comment: So, as said there, "prefer_final_locals (Incompatible with: unnecessary_final)" and "unnecessary_final (Incompatible with: prefer_final_locals.)". It's only a matter of taste, but again, var is shorter and the default on Dart documentation examples: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage

Comment: Later on that same page, it says that both are acceptable, and the only universal rule is to be consistent: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-follow-a-consistent-rule-for-var-and-final-on-local-variables